# Fixing vba copy rows data from a column to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am trying with this code. There are numerous rows in column 10 in my sheet Concur, but when i run the codes, it only copy paste the last row in my destination. I not sure whats go wrong....

```
Dim ConcurLastRow As Long
Set Concur = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Concur")

ConcurLastRow = Concur.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 11 To ConcurLastRow
Worksheets("Concur").Cells(i, 10).Copy

UploadtoSunLastRow = Worksheets("UploadtoSun").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Worksheets("Concur").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("UploadtoSun").Cells(UploadtoSunLastRow, 4)

Next i
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a loop here to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Column 1 to get the last row on both sheets but are populating column 4 on `worksheet("UploadtoSun")`.

You want to change:

```
UploadtoSunLastRow = Worksheets("UploadtoSun").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

to:

```
UploadtoSunLastRow = Worksheets("UploadtoSun").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

Now you are comparing the last row with the column you are adding rows to.

Though as pointed out by BigBen if you are grabbing a contiguous range and dumping to another contiguous range you can just copy the entire range over in one shot with no need for a loop.

This would do the same with no loop:

```
    Dim ConcurLastRow As Long
    Dim UploadtoSunLastRow As Long
    Dim concur As Worksheet
    Set concur = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Concur")

    ConcurLastRow = concur.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
    UploadtoSunLastRow = Worksheets("UploadtoSun").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    With concur
        .Range(.Cells(11, 10), .Cells(ConcurLastRow, 10)).Copy Worksheets("UploadtoSun").Cells(UploadtoSunLastRow, 4)
    End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the above!! Can i ask one more question? How can i paste value instead of copy without major editing the above codes ?